# How to sort a table by two columns in Contour?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I have a dataset and I want to sort the data in the table view by two columns, not just one. How can I achieve this in Contour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Sort board first you have the option "Add column to sort by" to select additional column to sort on.

[image: Sort by two columns]